# Can I get a text description of an ISO currency code in Java?

Tags: java, currency

Is there a way to get a text description of the currency represented by a Currency object in Java?

i.e. I have AZM, I want Azerbaijan Manat

Comment: Not that I am aware of good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set up your own mapping. 
Google or Stackoverflow questions will point to the [ISO site](http://www.iso.org/iso/currency_codes_list-1)

However you'll have to scrape the page as there seems to be no XML or text file as there is for country

Answer (score 4):

Such a mapping would again be `Locale`-dependent… I think your best bet would be to take a long, hard look at [ISO 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) and create a `Map` from currency code to currency name.

Answer (score 3):

It's not supported by Java but a few libraries can do this.

My number one choice would be ICU,

http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/Currency.html#getName%28java.util.Locale,%20int,%20boolean[]%29

This call can get you the name of a currency in multiple locales. ICU also supports all other i18n features not available in JRE. However, it's pretty big.

Another option is jPOS,

http://gl.jpos.org/

If you do anything with financial data, this is the de-facto standards. Watch for its license. Our lawyers didn't like it for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Class [java.util.Currency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) implements this since java 1.7.

```
    Currency curr = Currency.getInstance("AZM");
    System.out.println(curr.getCurrencyCode()); // AZM
    System.out.println(curr.getNumericCode());  // 31
    System.out.println(curr.getDisplayName());  // Azerbaijani Manat (1993-2006)
```

Unfortunatelly, this class is still far from usability... e.g. missing constructor from numericCode, some displayNames containings not event DisplayName, ...

Answer (score 2):

Not in the standard API. The data behind the Currency class is loaded from the package-private class `java.util.CurrencyData`, and there's simply no text description present there. You can look at it if you have the source code installed with your JDK.

Answer (score 1):

`openexchangerates.org` provides this info live online in machine-readable `JSON` format:

> `http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json`

It returns information as simple as this:

```
{
  "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
  "AFN": "Afghan Afghani",

  ...

  "ZMK": "Zambian Kwacha",
  "ZWL": "Zimbabwean Dollar"
}
```

It's almost free but there are some terms and conditions. [Here is the online documentation.](http://openexchangerates.org/documentation)

Comment: Is there the same thing but also with translations? I need also russian