# Android Currency Class - How Do you Get the Display Name for the Currency?

Tags: android, get, currency

I can easily set a Currency using it's ISO 4217 code, such as "USD". This will allow me to grab the dollar symbol using .getSymbol(), however, how the heck do I get the display name "dollar" out of the Currency?

I have a spinner, I'd like to populate with the names of currencies like "dollar", "euro", "yen", etc. however, I can't extract these from the ISO 4217 codes. Shouldn't this be quite easy?

Please note, I can't use simple string arrays to solve this. That's because I grab the default locale and  add it's currency to the spinner mentioned above. This is the reason I need to be able to grab currency display names dynamically, I don't know all the currencies users may use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Refer to this question.

[Can I get a text description of an ISO currency code in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458912/can-i-get-a-text-description-of-an-iso-currency-code-in-java)

It might answer your question. There are many answers on that page.

Comment: Wow, that's a bit rough. The feature is minor, those workarounds are too much bulk for the task at hand. I believe, unfortunately the most efficient way to do this is to grab the World's 20 most popular currencies, use a string array and offer these choices only. I believe this is reasonable and how most apps do currency anyway. It's too bad they simply couldn't have added a method to grab the display name, it's clearly coded using the ISO 4217 standard...

Comment: Thank you for at least trying to answer, I appreciate it Sas.